# How come I didn't receive the bounty?

Tags: support, bounties

I have [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57013398/8274756) a bounty question on Stack Overflow, but I did not received any bounty and I don't know why.

From [What is a bounty? How can I start one?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) I understand that If I have an answer with 2 upvotes (or more) on it and it is the most voted answer after the grace period ended I will receive the bounty/ half of it.

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount.

**The grace period has ended and the question bounty was not given to anybody by the question asker.**

My question is, my answer:

- Was the first answer posted.
- Is the most voted question.
- Has more than 2 upvotes.

This is not "I am upset that I was not given reputation question", but a general question that is relevant to all Stack Exchange sites about bounty questions.

Comment: You answered the question before the bounty started. Per the FAQ [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work), only answers posted *during the bounty period* are eligible for automatic bounty awarding.

Comment: Also, emphasis on "created after the bounty started" in the quote you mention.

Comment: I have actually answered the question after the bounty started, but if  I don't remember correctly this could be the most reasonable case here.

Comment: No, you answered on July 12, and the bounty [was started on July 17](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57013268/revisions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer was **submitted** on July 12 and the bounty can't have been started by then (the question itself hadn't been 48 hours at the point), so your answer is not eligible for the bounty.

Your subsequent edit on July 19 does not change the fact that it was first created on July 12.

Answer (score 3):

You can look at [the timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57013268/timeline) of the answer you linked to in order to see when something happened. There you can see that you answered on July 12th at 20:01 and the bounty was added on July 17 at 20:37. Therefore your answer wasn't eligible for receiving the bounty.